# How to add a functional contact form at my home page in django by using {% include %} or any other method?

Tags: django, forms, blogs, contacts

I am fairly new at django and i'm trying to make a blog website. I want the blogsite to have a contact page in it so users can send email to the author. I created a contact.html and made a contact function in views and added the path in urls.py (/contact.html). If I go to (/contact.html) and fill the form it works as intended and sends the email. But when I use the {%include %} tag and add it to my homepage it stops working from home and submitting the form doesn't do anything.

```
contact.html:

{% if message_name %}
<h1>{{ message_name }} Your message has been submitted. We will get back to you soon..</h1>
{% else %}
<form action="#" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name='message-name' placeholder="Your Name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name='message-lname' placeholder="Your Name"><br><br>
    <input type="email" name='message-email' placeholder="Your Email"><br><br>
    <textarea name='message' placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
   <br/><br/><br/>
    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    <br><br><br>
</form>

{% endif %}


views.py:
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message_name = request.POST['message-name']
        message_lname = request.POST['message-lname']
        message_email = request.POST['message-email']
        message = request.POST['message']

        #send mail
        send_mail(
            'message from ' + message_name + ' ' + message_lname + ' their email ' + message_email ,
            message, 
            message_email, 
            ['myemail@gmail.com'],
        )

        return render(request, 'blog/contact.html', {'message_name':message_name})
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/contact.html', {})


urls.py:

      path('contact.html', views.contact, name='contact'),

base.html:

...
...

{% include 'blog/contact.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for sure with the information you have provided, but one possibility is that you've inserted the `include` tag outside of your content blocks.

For example, it should be like this:

```
{% block content %}

    {% include "blog/contact.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

But like I say this is just one possibility. Also look to make sure you have loaded all the necessary tags in your included file.

A general good way to debug would be to copy and paste the included file in the template and then it would be easier to see which errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Yeaah.. So I figured it out. What went wrong was that I defined the contact function in views and then used the render(request) with contact.html... So when I used the contact form in the home page it couldn't use the views.contact because I had it set up to use views.home function. What I did was is that I copied all the code in the contact function from views and pasted it in the home function in views. That worked for me perfectly.